# Python Code for Rock, Paper & Scissor Gave Wrong Output

Tags: python, output, game-physics, pyscripter

Essence of this code is to depict Rock, Paper and Scissors game using Python language basically with `for` loop and `if`...`else` statements. I used PyScripter to run the code on Python 3.7.2 as engine. The `def main()` and `if __name__ == '__main__'` are PyScripter codes for running the machine

```
import random

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


tie_sum, comp_sum, human_sum = 0, 0, 0
name = input('Enter your firstname here: ')

for i in range(5):
    tie_sum += tie_sum
    comp_sum += comp_sum
    human_sum += human_sum

    comp_guess = random.randint(1, 3)
    print(f'The computer guess option is {comp_guess}')
    human_guess = int(input('Enter 1 as (rock), 2 as (paper) or 3 as (scissors):'))

    if comp_guess == 1 and human_guess == 3:
        comp_sum += 1
    elif comp_guess == 1 and human_guess is 2:
        human_sum += 1
    elif comp_guess == 2 and human_guess == 3:
        human_sum += 1
    elif comp_guess == 3 and human_guess == 1:
        human_sum += 1
    elif comp_guess == 3 and human_guess == 2:
        comp_sum += 1
    elif comp_guess == 2 and human_guess == 1:
        comp_sum += 1
    else:
        tie_sum += 1

print(f'The number of tie in this game is {tie_sum}')

if comp_sum > human_sum:
    print('The winner of this game is the Computer.')
    print(f'The comp_sum is {comp_sum}')
elif comp_sum < human_sum:
    print(f'The winner of this game is {name}.')
    print(f'The human sum is {human_sum}')
else:
    print('This game ends in tie.')
    print(f'The tie sum is {tie_sum}')
```

Comment: The first 3 lines inside the loop are clearly wrong - they double each of the 3 scores, for no reason that I can make out.

Comment: Please show examples of your input, the output from your code, and the output you expected, i.e. give details of what the problem is, because ‘wrong output is not diagnosable without these details.

Comment: Thanks a lot sirs for the comments. Robin Zigmond your suggestion worked and it was the solution. I'm greatful sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is the first three lines in the for loop. You are increasing the sum of computer, human and tie while checking the condition and when you the loop iterates again, it sums up again. Here's the modified code:

```py
import random

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


tie_sum, comp_sum, human_sum = 0, 0, 0
name = input('Enter your firstname here: ')

for i in range(5):
    

    comp_guess = random.randint(1, 3)
    
    human_guess = int(input('Enter 1 as (rock), 2 as (paper) or 3 as (scissors):'))
    print(f'The computer guess option is {comp_guess}')
    if comp_guess == 1 and human_guess == 3:
        comp_sum += 1
    elif comp_guess == 1 and human_guess == 2:
        human_sum += 1
    elif comp_guess == 2 and human_guess == 3:
        human_sum += 1
    elif comp_guess == 3 and human_guess == 1:
        human_sum += 1
    elif comp_guess == 3 and human_guess == 2:
        comp_sum += 1
    elif comp_guess == 2 and human_guess == 1:
        comp_sum += 1
    else:
        tie_sum += 1

print(f'The number of tie in this game is {tie_sum}')

if comp_sum > human_sum:
    print('The winner of this game is the Computer.')
    print(f'The comp_sum is {comp_sum}')
elif comp_sum < human_sum:
    print(f'The winner of this game is {name}.')
    print(f'The human sum is {human_sum}')
else:
    print('This game ends in tie.')
    print(f'The tie sum is {tie_sum}')
```

Also, there was another modification, the computer guess is supposed to be printed after human's guess. I fixed that too. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bhavesh Lohana for your comment and solution. It was the solution. I'm greatful sir. Great work.